# What does the author mean here by the congruence relation generated by -?

Tags: equivalence-relations, congruence-relations, wheel-theory

I am reading up on Wheel Theory using the notes found at https://www2.math.su.se/reports/2001/11/2001-11.pdf. There really doesn't seem to be many online notes for this topic. It starts by motivating wheels by looking at the ring of fractions, but I am confused by what it states on page ${4}$:

> ${A\times S}$ is a product of monoids, with ${\sim_S}$ a congruence relation on it. Let ${\equiv_S}$ be the congruence relation generated on the monoid ${A\times A}$ by ${\sim_S}$. Then ${(x,y)\equiv_S (x',y')\Leftrightarrow \exists\ s,s' \in S: (sx,sy) = (s'x,s'y)}$

What exactly does it mean by ${\equiv_S}$ is generated by ${\sim_S}$?

Comment: It means the smallest congruence that contains $\sim_S$ as a subset. Note that $\sim_S$ is a congruence on $A\times S$, so it cannot be a congruence on $A\times A$ (it is not reflexive when $S\neq A$). So take the intersection of all congruences on $A\times A$ that contain $\sim_S$ as a subset.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin when you say that it contains ${\sim_S}$ as a subset, do you simply mean that if you restrict to ${A\times S}$ then ${\equiv_S}$ is the same relation as ${\sim_S}$? What do you mean also to take the intersection of congruences?

Comment: A congruence is an equivalence relation. An equivalence relation is a set of ordered pairs. So a congruence on $T$ is a subset of $T\times T$ with extra properties. Here, $\sim_S$ is a subset of $(A\times S)\times(A\times S)$. A congruence on $A\times A$ is a subset of $(A\times A)\times(A\times A)$. Since $A\times S\subseteq A\times A$, $\sim_S$ is also a subset of $(A\times A)\times(A\times A)$. "Intersection of congruences" means their intersection as sets.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh right I see ok. I haven't seen a relation being defined as a subset of ordered pairs before. So a congruence on ${T}$ is a subset of ${T\times T}$ such that ${(t,t') \in T\times T}$ implies ${(t',t) \in T\times T}$ (symmetry), ${(t,t) \in T\times T}$ for every $t$ (reflexivity), and ${(t,t') \in T\times T}$, ${(t',t'') \in T\times T}$ implies ${(t,t'') \in T\times T}$ (transitivity) and also it behaves well under addition/multiplication / whatever operation?

Comment: Yes, Equivalently instead of "behaves well", "is a substructure of $T\times T$ (with coordinatewise operations)."

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ahhh right yeps I see now. Thank you very much for your help, I really do appreciate it